# MVVM-WPF: Polymorphic data binding to Interface

Tags: oop, mvvm

In my model I have an Interface IVehicle which implemented by Car, Motorcycle, Train ... classes now I want to use IVehicle as the data source within my viewmodel in binding to the wpf view to benefit using polymorphism so I can switch between Car, Motorcycle, Train ... but I don't know how to implement this scenario in viewmodel knowing that the model getting populated using wcf services.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have some code and probably some more details? Why don't you just add a property of type `IVehicle` to your ViewModel? Then you could bind to the properties that are defined in the interface because all concrete types (Car, Motorcycle...) must implement them.

Comment: @gehho: sorry for not including code because this just simplification of part of the real model. the main issue is how at run time I can decide which implementation of IVehicle to be used based on user selection in user interface. I thought about your suggestion but with separating the view to two parts one for the not changing properties existing in IVehicle and the other part which will change according to concrete type Car, Motorcycle, ... I thought about using simple factory handle user selections and decide which concrete class to use.